# How to animate simple View to move from bottom to top?

Tags: android, android-animation

i need to implement some type of Progress bar. It should be simple view, which moves from top to bottom infinitely. I have concept art with this feature:
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Gjj5HSumgYc/VXn_PIRtXrI/AAAAAAAADmU/R9rp3GBDU3c/w445-h791-no/castro_splash.gif

Yellow zone should move from to bottom. How can animate this?

Comment: show some code, what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter( View view )
{
    RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.rootLayout );
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );
    int statusBarOffset = dm.heightPixels - root.getMeasuredHeight();

    int originalPos[] = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

    int xDest = dm.widthPixels/2;
    xDest -= (view.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
    int yDest = dm.heightPixels - (view.getMeasuredHeight()/2) - statusBarOffset;

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDest - originalPos[0] , 0, yDest - originalPos[1] );
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setFillAfter( true );
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

Comment: This method move view just to center, i need another effect. I have updated my question with gif animation.